# How to post data in nested serializer using id field

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to post data in nested serializer using only `id` field, but it does not work.

This project is for making orders in restaurants

### What i want to see

Here is how i push data:

```json
{
    "is_done": false,
    "dishes": [
        {"dish":1}
    ]
}
```

The GET request looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": 14,
    "is_done": false,
    "dishes": [
        {
            "dish": 1,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to see it like this

```json
{
    "id": 14,
    "is_done": false,
    "dishes": [
        {
            "dish": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Simple dish 1",
                "price": "200.00"
            },
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

### Here is my python code

OrderItemSerializer 
OrderSerializer

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            'dish',
            'quantity',
        )


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = OrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id',
            'is_done',
            'dishes',
            # 'created_at',
            # 'updated_at',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_items = validated_data.pop('dishes')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for dish in order_items:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **dish)
        return order
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        order_items = validated_data.pop('dishes')

        instance.is_done = validated_data.get('is_done', instance.is_done)
        instance.save()

        for dish in order_items:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(order=instance)
            order_item.dish = dish['dish']
            order_item.quantity = dish['quantity']
            order_item.save()

        return instance
```

#### Models

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='dishes',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: do you want to create new objects using POST or retrieve data with the format that you said using GET?

Comment: I want to get the data in that format

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `serializer` for dish to your `OrderItemSerializer` which represents data the way you want it.
so it will be:

```py
class DishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dish
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'price',
        )
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dish = DishSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            'dish',
            'quantity',
        )

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = OrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id',
            'is_done',
            'dishes',
            # 'created_at',
            # 'updated_at',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_items = validated_data.pop('dishes')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for dish in order_items:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **dish)
        return order
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        order_items = validated_data.pop('dishes')

        instance.is_done = validated_data.get('is_done', instance.is_done)
        instance.save()

        for dish in order_items:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.get(order=instance)
            order_item.dish = dish['dish']
            order_item.quantity = dish['quantity']
            order_item.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: It works but now i get ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_orderitem.dish_id``` , and when i try to update the dish in the order i gives me ```KeyError: 'dish'```

Comment: for posting and updating you need to overwrite create and update method in `OrderItemSerializer` just like you did in `OrderSerializer`.

Comment: These overwrited methods doesn't work in ```OrderItemSerializer```. The methods works only in ```OrderSerializer```

Comment: I found a problem, when I'm trying to create or update the ```dishes``` are empty.  

For example
in ```OrderSerializer``` method ```create``` ,  i'm trying to print the ```order_items```  it's empty